# google.maps.event.addListener and fall calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, event-handling

I create this marker, and I'd like to attach and handler to the marker and one to an object inside the infowindow showed when I click on the marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: posizione,
    map: map,
    title: "Title"
});

markerClick = function () {
    templateFinestra.find('.titolo').html("New Title");
    var prova = templateFinestra.find('.myLink');
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(prova, 'click', alert("Hello"));

    infoWindow.setContent(templateFinestra.html());
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);       
};

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerClick);
```

but when I click on marker, I see the alert! Why? And how can I create 2 separate handler? (one for the marker, one for the infowindow link opened when I click on marker).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are executing it immediately and giving it's return as a function (which it isn't).

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(prova, 'click', function(){
    alert("Hello")
});
```

Comment: Uhm, you are right! But now if I click on `prova` nothing happens!

Comment: You are destroying the event when you call `templateFinestra.html()`, remove `.html()`. If that still doesn't work, then you need to bind the event after you open the infoWindow on the content of the infoWindow.

Comment: ? But I need to place that code inside the infowindow. If I remove .html() it does append nothing

Comment: @markzzz Then you can't bind the event before opening the info window.

Comment: Tried binding the event after open the infowindow: the same! The alert won't appair

Comment: Most likely because you aren't selecting the correct element. You need to use `$(infoWindow.getContent()).find("myanchor").click(handler)` -- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow

Comment: Tried also this: it finds the element (tried to show the html(), it is correct), but the handler won't be attached

Comment: hmm... i wonder if getContent is just getting a copy of the content. Can you make it "go away" by using .remove()?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26558/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-markzzz)